# looping of python: how to loop list to find what elements of list begin with

Tags: python

Here are my instructions:
Below is a list of strings representing all the states. Write code that loops through it and counts the number of U.S. states whose name begins with a vowel ("Alabama" or "Ohio"). Assign this value to a variable called vowel_state_names.

This is the code I wrote but I know its not not correct for the task.
Here is my code:

```
states = [
        'Alaska', 'Alabama', 'Arkansas', 'Arizona', 'California', 'Colorado', 
        'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 
        'Iowa', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Massachusetts', 
        'Maryland', 'Maine', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Missouri', 
        'Mississippi', 'Montana', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Nebraska', 'New Hampshire', 
        'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'Nevada', 'New York', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 
        'Virginia', 'Vermont', 'Washington', 'Wisconsin', 'West Virginia', 'Wyoming' 
         ]

vowel_state_names = []
for names in states:
  startswithvowel = False  # rather than try to prove starts with vowel
  if 'a' in names:
    if 'e' in names:
      if 'i' in names:
        if 'o' in names:
          if 'u' in names:
            if 'y' == names[-1]:
              hasAllVowels = True
  if startswithvowel:
    vowel_state_names.append( word )
print( vowel_state_names )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can try in below format.

```
states = [
        'Alaska', 'Alabama', 'Arkansas', 'Arizona', 'California', 'Colorado',
        'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
        'Iowa', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Massachusetts',
        'Maryland', 'Maine', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Missouri',
        'Mississippi', 'Montana', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Nebraska', 'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'Nevada', 'New York', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania',
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah',
        'Virginia', 'Vermont', 'Washington', 'Wisconsin', 'West Virginia', 'Wyoming'
         ]
State_names=[]
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
for names in states:
    if names[0] in vowels:
        State_names.append(names)
print(State_names)
```

Comment: thanks so much! DO you have an email? That is exactly what I was trying to do

Comment: yap, aravitisaisiva1599@outlook.com

Answer (score 0):

I am also a newbie to python, but check if this works :

```
vowel_state_names = []
vowels = ['A','E','I','O','U']
for names in states:
   for i in vowels:
      if names.startswith(i):
         Vowel_State_names.append(names)
print(vowel_state_names)
```

['Alaska', 'Alabama', 'Arkansas', 'Arizona', 'Iowa', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Utah']

Comment: is that a "loop" though?

Comment: yes it's a for loop, checks if each beginning letter of an element starts with a vowel.

Answer (score 0):

**Use regex**

```
import re


states = [
        'Alaska', 'Alabama', 'Arkansas', 'Arizona', 'California', 'Colorado',
        'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
        'Iowa', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Massachusetts',
        'Maryland', 'Maine', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Missouri',
        'Mississippi', 'Montana', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Nebraska', 'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'Nevada', 'New York', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania',
        'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah',
        'Virginia', 'Vermont', 'Washington', 'Wisconsin', 'West Virginia', 'Wyoming'
         ]

Vowel_State_names=[]
regex = '^[aeiouAEIOU][A-Za-z0-9_]*'

for names in states:
    if (re.search(regex, names)):
        Vowel_State_names.append(names)

print(Vowel_State_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) if you want to know how many of the states begin with it:

```
sum(1 for state in states if state[0] in frozenset(('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')))
```

To get the names, use that same generator, replacing `1` with `state`:

```
tuple(state for state in states if state[0] in frozenset(('A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')))
```